# Topological structure on symmetrical product.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

For a real smooth surface (or just an algebraic curve over $\mathbb{C}$) $\Sigma$, the g-symmetrical ($g \in \mathbb{N}$) product of it is $Sym^{g}\Sigma:=\Sigma^{\times g}/S_{g}$ where the permutation group $S_{g}$ acts on $\Sigma^{\times g}$ by permuting the entries.

Then, I'm not sure what is the topological structure on $Sym^{g}\Sigma$. I confronted the symmetrical product while reading https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0101206 (lemma 2.6, for example) but I have no idea what is the topology (and curves) on it.

EDIT: I got the idea that $Sym^{g}\Sigma$ is again an algebraic curve over $\mathbb{C}$ thus a Riemann surface. But what is the explicit structure on it, then?

Comment: Do you know the quotient topology ?

Comment: @MaximeRamzi I know, but I am wondering whether the quotient topology coincides with the definition here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_product_of_an_algebraic_curve)

Comment: The beginning of the page explicitly says it's "the quotient space". It so happens that in the complex case, this also has an algebraic curve structure

Comment: Ohhh, it's my bad. Thank you so much ;)